# Remove \t\n FROM JSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a table that stores an email body:

[image]

I extract into JSON format in a stored procedure:

```
"emailTexts": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "body": "Dear Sir\r\n Greetings!\r\n ThankYou",
  }
```

How can I remove `\t\n` at the same time as I will need to send the same format to another system.

Comment: If you use JSON methods to work with that value I imagine they will already deal with it correctly https://dbfiddle.uk/akZINR6N

Comment: You want to remove \t\n, but then you also want to keep them. What you asking makes no sense. Why do you want to remove them at all?

Comment: Json cannot contain newlines, so \n is the json version of new lines. When your "other" system parses jsons, it converts back from \n to newlines, and all will be well.

Comment: Also : print REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_VALUE(@J, '$.emailTexts[0].body'), NCHAR(13), ''), NCHAR(10), '')

Comment: Please show your code, and explain what result you want (because `\n` is the only way to encode newlines in JSON)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure you would want to do such a thing. Anyway, you could use Replace(). ie:

```
DECLARE @t VARCHAR(MAX)
    = '"emailTexts": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "body": "Dear Sir\r\n Greetings!\r\n ThankYou",
  }';

SELECT REPLACE(@t, '\r\n', '');
```

Or (to deal with all occurrences of \r \n \t):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@t, '\r', ''),'\n',''),'\t','');
```

PS: If you would do this on large data then consider creating a CLR function instead.

Comment: If I replace it , It will go from JSON . I need to send this json to other system, it has to be in the same format on how I stored in my DB.

Comment: @dmall, How is that stored in db? You didn't give that information at all, did you? I wonder what would it matter but give the storage format and what you mean.

Comment: If there was no SPACE you would get  Greetings!ThankYou

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, so what? You can use a space instead of '' if you want to. Touching to original layout is not a problem but having or not a space is, do you think?